# Character literal in Java?

Tags: java

So I just started reading "Java In A Nutshell", and on Chapter One it states that:

"To include a character literal in a Java program, simply place it between single quotes"
i.e.

```
char c = 'A';
```

What exactly does this do^? I thought char only took in values 0 - 65,535. I don't understand how you can assign 'A' to it?

You can also assign 'B' to an int?

```
int a = 'B'
```

The output for 'a' is 66. Where/why would you use the above^ operation?

I apologise if this is a stupid question.

My whole life has been a lie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`char` is actually an integer type. It stores the 16-bit Unicode integer value of the character in question.

You can look at something like http://asciitable.com to see the different values for different characters.

Comment: No, it stores the UTF-16 code unit of the character in question. That way it can handle values which aren't in ASCII...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Just double checked the documentation and updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `char` in Java is an integer type.  It is an unsigned 16-bit integer value.  The first 128 character codes in Unicode are the ASCII codes, so it can be said that a `char` stores a UTF-16 code that *may* also be an ASCII code.  For most intents -- if you're not dealing with foreign languages or "graphics characters" -- you can regard it as ASCII.

Comment: BTW. I believe that chars can represent Unicode code unit that are bigger than 16-bits by the use of 2 chars to represent one code point.

Comment: Yeah but, why would you want to "store the 16-bit Unicode integer value of the character in question." What purpose does that serve?

Comment: @Eggy - You have to store character values somehow.  How else would you do it?

Comment: @HotLicks “For most intents -- if you're not dealing with foreign languages or "graphics characters" -- you can regard it as ASCII.”—Foreign? Take a random article from _the NYT_. Chances are that it contains non-ASCII (punctuation like dashes and quotation marks).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at an ASCII chart, the character "A" has a value of 41 hex or 65 decimal.  Using the `'` character to bracket a single character makes it a character literal.  Using the double-quote (`"`) would make it a String literal.

Assigning `char someChar = 'A';` is exactly the same as saying `char someChar = 65;`.

As to why, consider if you simply want to see if a String contains a decimal number (and you don't have a convenient function to do this).  You could use something like:

```
bool isDecimal = true;
for (int i = 0; i < decString.length(); i++) {
    char theChar = decString.charAt(i);
    if (theChar < '0' || theChar > '9') {
        isDecimal = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java char literals represent UTF-16 (character encoding schema) code units. What you got from UTF-16 is mapping between integer values (and the way they are saved in memory) with corresponding character (graphical representation of unit code).

You can enclose characters in single quotes - this way you don't need to remember UTF-16 values for characters you use. You can still get the integer value from character type and put if for example in int type (but generally not in short, they both use 16 bits but short values are from -32768 to 32767 and char values are from 0 to 65535 or so).

Comment: Signed 16 bit ints (Java `short`) run from -32768 to 32767.  An unsigned 16-bit integer (Java `char`) can have a value from 0 to 65535 (though a number of the high-end code points are reserved for special purposes, so the practical range of representable characters is significantly lower, unless you go into "escape" mode).

Comment: Thanks for correction. I calculated char and short ranges in head - corrected them now.

Comment: Any programmer worth his salt has those numbers committed to memory.  (I'll admit that is still need to look up 2147483647, though.)