# what char ch = ‘Z’ would store in ch?

Tags: c

As i am confuse what will ch stored in it. is it **ascii value or 'z'** as some sites are saying it stores ascii and some says its stores 'z'.
link saying the answer is 'z' : http://cprogrammingworld4u.blogspot.in/2011/07/chapter-1-getting-started.html

link saying answer is ascii : https://www.careercup.com/question?id=12511679

Comment: In C you don't really distinguish between `z` and the ascii value of `z`. They are both valid literals for exactly the same object in memory.

Comment: It's the same thing.  `'z'` is just syntax for the character value of `z`.  If you want to know what that value is, simply print it as an integer.

Comment: so it stores ascii value in the memory location

Comment: It's an integer constant.  You can do anything with the value that you can with any other integer constant.  You can print it, you can assign it, you can pass it as a function argument.  Take your pick.  It's an integer constant.

Answer (score 10):

In C, `'z'` is a constant of type `int` with value `122` (assuming you're on an ASCII machine, which you probably are). Both of your sources are in agreement - they're the same thing.

As an example, just print it all the different ways you care about. Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch = 'z';
    char i  = 122;
    printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
    printf("%c %d\n", i, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it:

```
$ make example && ./example
z 122
z 122
```

Comment: does it change for **java** are it is same as c

Comment: It's [similar in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849986/character-literal-in-java), yes.

Comment: so you are saying answer is both ascii and 'z' or what

Comment: I'm saying there's no difference. It is both. `'z'` and `122` are identical as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @rajatsharma In Java `char` is 16-bit rather than 8-bit, so that alone shows that they are not quite the same, though Java accepts things like `'a'` + 1 and seems to treat `char` as basically a number type. I'm sure that there must be some differences between Java chars and C chars beyond their size, though I don't know enough Java to say just what those differences are.

Comment: @JohnColeman In Java, when you say `'a' + 1`, the `'a'` (a `char`) is promoted to an `int` first, before being added to the 1 (which is also an `int`). In C, `'a'` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... both ! Here is a snippet that may help you understand better :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch = 'z';
    printf("%c\n", ch);
    printf("%d\n", (int)ch);
}
```

When you consider ch as a char, it is indeed 'z', that is stored. But if you cast it to an int, you are going to get the ASCII value for 'z', which is 122.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: The cast to `int` is superfluous: `printf` is a variadic function which means that the `char` is auto-promoted to `int` when passed in.

Comment: This answer is correct, but a bit misleading. The `(int)` cast isn't necessary because of the default argument promotions, and there's no actual 'conversion' taking place anywhere.

Comment: but in memory it change only store either 'z' or its ascii value..explicity we change change

Comment: @rajatsharma - I don't think I understand that comment. You can take *any* program, and replace all instances of `122` with `'z'` and vice versa, and get exactly the same binary out of the compiler.

Comment: What will it store in the memory location carl Norum

Answer (score 0):

It "usually" stores the ASCII value.

It therefore is possible to perform integer operations on an char. The ASCII value is used to map it to the right ASCII character. You can even increment it or reduce it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

char ch = 90;
printf("%c\n\n", ch);
ch = 64;
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    ch++;
    printf("%c\n", ch);
}

}
```

The for loop prints out A - Z. Notice how I've just incremented the value of ch by 1 in every iteration.

If you notice I have assigned ch a number. I could have even assigned it 'z'.

From a complete beginner perspective the thing that you must understand is that everything is stored as '0' or '1' in memory. This unreadable sequence of 0's and 1's in converted into the text you see on the screen (decoding).

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, it stores the value of that character in the execution instruction set, which is usually ASCII, but doesn't *have* to be. Your program will print some nonsense on an EBCDIC machine, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`'Z'` us a character constant. Its type is `int`. When you use

```
char c = 'Z';
```

the integer value stored in `c` could be different based on the character encoding used by your compiler. If it uses ASCII encoding, then it will store the ASCII representation of `'Z'` in `c`, which is `90` decimal. If it uses EBCDIC encoding, then it will store the EBCDIC representation of `'Z'` in `c`, which is `233` decimal.

In order to write portable programs, you'll have to ignore the integer value stored in `c`. Certain things you can count on for both those encodings are:

1. `'9' - '0'` is equal to `9`
2. `'Z' - 'A'` is equal to  `'z' - 'a'`

I am not aware of other encodings in use where the above are not true.

References:
[ASCII encoding chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)
[EBCDIC encoding chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout)

Comment: 2 and 3 are *not* guaranteed. Just look at the EBCDIC chart you linked to.

Comment: @CarlNorum, indeed. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Is your new #2 guaranteed? I thought the only guarantee was that the digits were consecutive.

Comment: They are true for ASCII and EBCDIC encoding. I don't know whether there are other encodings for which that is not true.

Comment: @CarlNorum I think  you're right, I don't find anything in the standard except the mention for consecutive digits.

Comment: @Holt, I don't see anything in the standard that says anything about the character constants for digits being consecutive either. It just happens to be true for both ASCII and EBCDIC encoding. If you know where to find what you are saying, please let me know. It will be instructive for me.

Comment: @RSahu In *5.2.1/3* (*Character sets*): "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous." (Committee Draft **n1570**).